# Assign a function pointer passed in as a parameter

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Is it possible to pass in a function pointer to a function and have that function assign the function to use?

Below is an example of what I mean:

```
void sub(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    *c = *a + *b;
}

void add(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    *c = *a - *b;
}

void switch_function(void (*pointer)(int*, int*, int*), int i)
{
    switch(i){
        case 1:
            pointer = &add;
            break;
        case 2:
            pointer = &sub;
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    void (*point)(int*, int*, int*);

    switch_function(point, 1); // This should assign a value to `point`
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c = 0;
    (*point)(&a, &b, &c);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In this patricular case, you should **return** a function pointer.

Comment: It should really have a default case where `pointer` is set to NULL on bad input. Better to crash when that pointer is called than to risk calling some actual function.

Answer (score 2):

**You can create a pointer to a function pointer.**

Here is the syntax:

```
void (**pointer)(int*, int*, int*);
```

After you initialized it, you can then dereference this pointer to set your function pointer:

```
*pointer = &add;
*pointer = &sub;
```

---

So your function would look like this:

```
void switch_function(void (**pointer)(int*, int*, int*), int i)
{
    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            *pointer = &add;
            break;
        case 2:
            *pointer = &sub;
            break;
    }
}
```

...and you'd call it like this:

```
switch_function(&point, 1);
```

Comment: I think you can also tighten this up a bit more and replace (e.g.) `&add` with `add` as the latter is already the _address_ of `add`

Comment: Pointer to function pointer makes perfect sense, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is much easier if you use a typedef for your function pointer. Especially if you use a double indirection in your sample.

```
typedef void (*fptr)(int*, int*, int*);

void sub(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{   
    *c = *a - *b;
}

void add(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{   
    *c = *a + *b;
}

void switch_function(fptr *pointer, int i)
{
    switch(i){
        case 1:
            *pointer = &add;
            break;
        case 2:
            *pointer = &sub;
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    fptr point;

    switch_function(&point, 1);
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c = 0;
    (**point)(&a, &b, &c);

    return 0;
}
```